# Converting values between view and controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, model-view-controller

What's the suggested way of converting values between a controller and a view if they don't match each other?

```
// Basic model with enum property
public class MyModel {
    public State MyState { get; set; }
}

// Enum denoting 3 states
public enum State {
    Ready,
    Set,
    Go
}

// API/MVC/Module/SignalR controller
public class MyController : MiddlewareController {
    public MyController() {
        Get = _ => {
            return View["myView", new MyModel()];
        };
    }
}

// myView
<div class="@Model.State"></div>
```

Now, the string representations of the enum values are "Ready", "Set" and "Go", but in my view, I need ".red", ".yellow", ".green".

Of course, in my controller, I could make a function that returns the appropriate CSS value, but that feels just wrong because I'm leaking view-concerns into my controller. Is there something like a value-converter?

Comment: why don t you just add the status as a css selector, like .red,.ready { background-color:red; }

Comment: @OnurTOPAL 1) Conventions. My enum value is called "Ready", the CSS class would be ".ready" - that doesn't match. 2) The "Ready" state is only known to the application, not to the view.

Comment: Create HtmlHelper where you can implement your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you cannot use the css as I suggested I think key-value dictionary is the way to go. Especially this is a site wide issue.

```
public static Dictionary<State, string> StatusClassName = new Dictionary<State, string>();
StatusClassName.Add(State.Ready, "red");
...
```

after that you can use what ever way you want like;

```
StatusClassName[Model.State]
```

or you can write an extension method to use like

```
Model.State.GetClassName();
```

Comment: Thank you. I really like your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it in view:

```
@{
   string className = string.Empty;
   switch (Model.State)
   {
       case State.Ready:className = "red"; break;
       case State.Set:className = "green"; break;
       case State.Go: className = "yellow"; break;
   }
}

<div class="@className"></div>
```